# Notification in fragments

Tags: android, fragment, android-notifications

I have an Activity with two fragments. In one fragment, when the button 'Notify' is clicked, a notification object has to be created. Can someone give me an example on how to create a notification in a fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way as in an activity, so you can use an example from the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification).

The only difference is that you need to use `getActivity()` to get the system service:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```